# Any way to have free desktop icons placement on ubuntu 20.04 using gnome flashback (metacity)?

Tags: 20.04, icons, gnome-flashback

I use gnome flashback (metacity) for my desktop. Now that I've upgraded my 18.04 system to 20.04 I'm no longer able to position the desktop icons where I like.
I've tried:
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-flashback.desktop.icons placement 'free'
but nothing changed.
Did someone solve the problem?
Giorgio.

Comment: That mode is not implemented in `gnome-flashback` - https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-flashback/-/issues/41.